# jQuery AJAX POST to current page with attribute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is an example of my own page.

```
<?php
$do = $_GET['do'];
switch($do){
case 'finalTask':
 if(isset($_POST['url'])){
   echo "It's Ok!";
 }else{
   echo "Problem!";
 }
}
```

This is also written in the same page.

```
<input type='text' id='siteName'>
<button type='submit' id='send'>Send</button>
<div id='info'></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#send').click(function(){
     var name = $('#siteName').val();
     var dataStr = 'url=' + name;

     $.ajax({
             url:"index.php?do=finalTask",
             cache:false,
             data:dataStr,
             type:"POST",
             success:function(data){
                  $('#info').html(data);
             }
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

When I try to input and press the send button. Nothing happened..... What's wrong with the code?

Comment: did you checked console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure file name is ***index.php***
- You need to make sure that you check in the php code when to output the form and when the
- Format of ajax post request is incorrect in your case.
- **You forgot to import JQuery JS script**, without that you can not use JQuery. (at least at this point of time)

-

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['do'])) { // Make sure that you don't get the form twice after submitting the data
    ?>
    <input type='text' id='siteName'>
    <button type='submit' id='send'>Send</button>
    <div id='info'></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#send').click(function () {
                var name = $('#siteName').val();
                var dataStr = 'url=' + name;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?do=finalTask",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {url: dataStr},  // you need to send as name:value format.
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#info').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
} else {
    error_reporting(E_ERROR); // Disable warning and enable only error reports.
    $do = $_GET['do'];
    switch ($do) {
        case 'finalTask':
            if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
                echo "It's Ok!";
            } else {
                echo "Problem!";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no form in your page, just form elements. Can you wrap them in a form:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type='text' id='siteName'>
    <button type='submit' id='send'>Send</button>
</form>
```